# how can i display json array to python dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a json file.

```
[
    {
        'orderId': 1811,
        'deliveryId': '000001811-1634732661563000',
        'shippingBook': '[{"qtyOrdered":1,"bookNoList":["B8303-V05","B8304-V05","B8305-V05","B8306-V05","B8307-V05"],"courseCode":"A8399-S26"},{"courseCode":"A1399-S70","qtyOrdered":1,"bookNoList":["B1301-V06","B1302-V06","B1303-V06","B1304-V06","B1305-1-V06","B1305-2-V06","B1306-V06","B1307-V06"]}]',

    }
]
```

but how can i display in dataframe in format
[image]

thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the pandas documentation?  What have you tried?

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? It may need to organize it manually in DataFrame - and this may need normal `for`-loop to work with elements on list `'shippingBook'`

Comment: you have string in `'shippingBook'` so it may need module JSON to convert it to python list with dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You have string in `'shippingBook'` which may need `json.loads()` to convert it to Python's list with dictionaries.

And you could use normal `for`-loops to convert all data to normal list with expected data - and later convert it to `DataFrame`

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {
        'orderId': 1811,
        'deliveryId': '000001811-1634732661563000',
        'shippingBook': '[{"qtyOrdered":1,"bookNoList":["B8303-V05","B8304-V05","B8305-V05","B8306-V05","B8307-V05"],"courseCode":"A8399-S26"},{"courseCode":"A1399-S70","qtyOrdered":1,"bookNoList":["B1301-V06","B1302-V06","B1303-V06","B1304-V06","B1305-1-V06","B1305-2-V06","B1306-V06","B1307-V06"]}]',

    }
]

# --- organize data ---

all_rows = []

for order in data:
    order_id = order['orderId']
    delivery_id = order['deliveryId']
    for book in json.loads(order['shippingBook']):
        row = [order_id, delivery_id, book['courseCode'], book['bookNoList']]
        #print(row)
        all_rows.append(row)

# --- convert to DataFrame ---        

df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows, columns=['orderId', 'deliveryId', 'courseCode', 'bookNoList'])

print(df.to_string())   # `to_string()` to display all data without `...`
```

Result:

```
   orderId                  deliveryId courseCode                                                                                    bookNoList
0     1811  000001811-1634732661563000  A8399-S26                                       [B8303-V05, B8304-V05, B8305-V05, B8306-V05, B8307-V05]
1     1811  000001811-1634732661563000  A1399-S70  [B1301-V06, B1302-V06, B1303-V06, B1304-V06, B1305-1-V06, B1305-2-V06, B1306-V06, B1307-V06]
```

---

**EDIT:**

You may also try do the same directly in `DataFrame`.

It needs `explode` to split list into rows

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {
        'orderId': 1811,
        'deliveryId': '000001811-1634732661563000',
        'shippingBook': '[{"qtyOrdered":1,"bookNoList":["B8303-V05","B8304-V05","B8305-V05","B8306-V05","B8307-V05"],"courseCode":"A8399-S26"},{"courseCode":"A1399-S70","qtyOrdered":1,"bookNoList":["B1301-V06","B1302-V06","B1303-V06","B1304-V06","B1305-1-V06","B1305-2-V06","B1306-V06","B1307-V06"]}]',

    }
]

#df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert string to list with dictionares

df['shippingBook'] = df['shippingBook'].apply(json.loads)

# split list `'shippingBook'` into rows

df = df.explode('shippingBook')
df = df.reset_index()
del df['index']

# split elements into columns

#df['courseCode'] = df['shippingBook'].apply(lambda item:item['courseCode'])
#df['bookNoList'] = df['shippingBook'].apply(lambda item:item['bookNoList'])

df['courseCode'] = df['shippingBook'].str['courseCode']   # unexpected behaviour for string functions `.str`
df['bookNoList'] = df['shippingBook'].str['bookNoList']   # unexpected behaviour for string functions `.str`

# remove `'shippingBook'`

del df['shippingBook']
                
print(df.to_string())
```

And the same with `apply(pd.Series)` to convert list into columns.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {
        'orderId': 1811,
        'deliveryId': '000001811-1634732661563000',
        'shippingBook': '[{"qtyOrdered":1,"bookNoList":["B8303-V05","B8304-V05","B8305-V05","B8306-V05","B8307-V05"],"courseCode":"A8399-S26"},{"courseCode":"A1399-S70","qtyOrdered":1,"bookNoList":["B1301-V06","B1302-V06","B1303-V06","B1304-V06","B1305-1-V06","B1305-2-V06","B1306-V06","B1307-V06"]}]',

    }
]

#df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert string to list with dictionares

df['shippingBook'] = df['shippingBook'].apply(json.loads)

# split list `'shippingBook'` into rows

df = df.explode('shippingBook')
df = df.reset_index()
del df['index']

# split elements into columns

new_columns = df['shippingBook'].apply(pd.Series)

#df[['qtyOrdered', 'bookNoList', 'courseCode']] = new_columns
#del df['qtyOrdered']

#df[['bookNoList', 'courseCode']] = new_columns[['bookNoList', 'courseCode']]

df = df.join(new_columns[['bookNoList', 'courseCode']])

# remove `'shippingBook'`

del df['shippingBook']
                
print(df.to_string())
```

Comment: I added example which uses DataFrame functions (`explode`, `apply`) to do the same.